# Should I use 'memcpy' on class that contains a virtual method？If not, how to replace it?

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, memcpy

Here is my simplified code,

```cpp
class ParentDict {
public:
    virtual some_func();
    virtual reorganize() = 0;

protected:
    int _ssize;
    int _lsize;
}

class ChildDict : public ParentDict {
public:
    virtual some_func();
    virtual reorganize();  // deserialize _arrays here;

private:
    int _array_num;
    char* _arrays;
}

ChildDict* deserialize(void* pool, uint64_t offset) {
    void *ptr = (void *)((uint64_t)pool + offset);
    ChirdDict dict = *((ChildDict *) ptr);

    // HERE is the problem code
    memcpy((void *)ptr, &dict, sizeof(ptr));

    ((ChildDict *) ptr)->reorganize();
    return (ChildDict *)ptr;
}
```

This code is trying to deserialize some class from file, and it works well. But the CPP-rules-checking-system keeps complaining about **Using 'memcpy' on class that contains a virtual method.**

I wonder what does memcpy has done here. Maybe it is not safe to use memcpy on virtual class, but why the code works here? Can I replace it with better solutions?

Comment: what is "the CPP-rules-checking-system" ?

Comment: Whenever you feel the need to write a C-style cast you should take it as a sign that you're doing something bad that will most likely lead to undefined behavior. And unfortunately "seems to work" is one of the possibilities of undefined behavior, until you make a very slight change that might seem otherwise unrelated and everything breaks spectacularly.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Op is creating a ChildDict object, but it seems that it copies from it back to the memory location from which it was created in the first part.

Comment: @PetokLorand sorry, removed comment because I misread the code

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Sorry, my bad. "the CPP-rules-checking-system" is some cpp tool built by my company. This system will automatically check bugs before I submit my code.

Comment: By the way, the code as you show it *will* guaranteed lead to undefined behavior. You copy the *pointer* `_arrays` in the `memcpy` call, which means you have two objects whose `_arrays` member point to the exact same memory. If you have a destructor that does `delete [] _arrays` then when `dict` ends its life and is destructed, that will leave the other object with an invalid pointer (assuming this pointer is correct to begin with).

Comment: sorry, before I thought this is a nice question, but if the tool is built by your company then your colleagues should be able to tell you why memcopying a class with virtual method is rejected, though there are other problems with your code ;)

Comment: `ChildDict dict` will be out of range after this function, I think it is ok to delete _arrays.@formerlyknownas_463035818

Comment: May be I simplified this code to much, since this code is really old, and it works for a long time. I wander what should I do to replace memcpy?@formerlyknownas_463035818

Comment: Plain assignment? Placement `new`? Using `memcpy` only works for POD types, and classes with virtual functions aren't POD types.

Comment: Would like to hear an argumentation why this particular memcopy would end up with undefined behavior. memcopy copies memory and the memory of an object consists of only its members, not functions themselves, or? A virtual function cannot add new members after all. I'd rather assume that static checking tool is sensitive to the case that you would use this on a child class with different members because then, memcopy can indeed be error prone.

Comment: @AlexGeorg A virtual function usually adds the need for a vtable, the object needs a pointer to that vtable. So a virtual function can add new members. As long as this is just used to copy the object within the same process I don't see any direct issues with that though. That is rarely the case when you have a need to serialize data in my experience.

Comment: I find multiple issue with 'memcpy'. Is it intended to copy only sizeof(ptr) 4 or 8 bytes based on machine you are running? Is it intended to do just a shallow copy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually give an answer: To avoid memcopy, you have two major options:

1. Create custom serialize and deserialize functions that form or interpret a byte array "manually". Or if data size is not mattering too much, turn the data into a string with some delimiter between the variables.
2. Put all members that require serialization in a simple struct without virtual functions and make such a struct, a member of your classes.